# Is it needed to detach pthread to prevent memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-management, pthreads

In my programme, I handle new threads with

```
 pthread_t thread;
 pthread_create(&thread, NULL,
            c->someFunction, (void *) fd); //where fd is ID of the thread
```

The question is quite simple - if I just let the `someFunction` to finish, is it needed then in `C++` to call something e.g. `join` or anything else, to prevenet `memory leaks` or is the memory freed automatically??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [opengroup page for pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html),

> The pthread_join() function provides a simple mechanism allowing an
>   application to wait for a thread to terminate. After the thread
>   terminates, the application may then choose to clean up resources that
>   were used by the thread. For instance, after pthread_join() returns,
>   any application-provided stack storage could be reclaimed.
>
> The pthread_join() or pthread_detach() function should eventually be
>   called for every thread that is created with the detachstate attribute
>   set to PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE so that storage associated with the
>   thread may be reclaimed.

and from the [man page of pthread_join](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join)

> Failure to join with a thread that is joinable (i.e., one that is not
>   detached), pro‐
>          duces  a  "zombie  thread".  Avoid doing this, since each zombie thread consumes some
>          system resources, and when enough zombie threads have accumulated, it will no  longer
>          be possible to create new threads (or processes).
>
> There  is no pthreads analog of waitpid(-1, &status, 0), that is, "join with any ter‐
>         minated thread".
>
> If you believe you need this functionality, you  probably  need  to
>         rethink your application design.

If you do [pthread_detach](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_detach.html),

> The pthread_detach() function shall indicate to the implementation
>   that storage for the thread thread can be reclaimed when that thread
>   terminates

If you don't `detach` or `join` a `joinable` thread, it can cause waste of resources

Comment: Deleted my answer, yours is better.

Comment: So when I want to exit the application, is it a good practice to iterate through e.g. a `vector` of created threads and `deatch` them (eventually `detach` certain thread after it has finished its' work) ? I'm asking because I'm not sure if I understood the difference between `join` and `detach` well. But it seems to me, that I can be sure , that `detach` will terminate the thread, just after I call it, right?

Comment: If you make the thread as detached, the thread's resources will be freed when the thread is done with the work. Join is used for joining to a thread (if you do a join on some thread in main, main wont finish execution until the thread is terminated and its resourcces are freed). `join` and `detach` are used for different purposes. But they both do release the resources.Detach is not for terminating the thread, thread will terminate on its own.Detached means no one is waiting for the thread to terminate. (like in join, someone is waiting for the thread to terminate so it can be joined

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756882/detached-vs-joinable-posix-threads) discussion here too

Comment: @Dworza Read [this](http://www.domaigne.com/blog/computing/joinable-and-detached-threads/) link too to know about detached threads

Comment: @Dworza: For the ones that do not read long man pages: `pthread_detach()` does **not** release any resource nor terminates anything. It just configures the thread to have all its resources freed when it finally ends.

Comment: @alk Ya thats much better. Small and sweet.