# C++11 std::thread accepting function with rvalue parameter

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have some homework, and I have troubles understanding, (probably) how passing parameters to std::thread constructor works.

Assume following code (I deleted unneeded parts)

```
template<typename T, typename Task>
class Scheduler
{
    private:
        typedef std::unordered_map<std::size_t, T> Results;
        class Solver
        {
            public:
            Solver(Task&& task) : m_thread(&Solver::thread_function, std::move(task))
            {
                m_thread.detach();
            }

            Solver(Solver&& solver) = default; // required for vector::emplace_back
            ~Solver() = default;

            private:
            void thread_function(Task&& task)
            {
                task();
            }
            std::thread m_thread;
        };

    public:
        Scheduler() = default;
        ~Scheduler() = default;

        void add_task(Task&& task)
        {
            m_solvers.emplace_back(std::move(task));
        }

    private:
        std::vector<Solver> m_solvers;
};

template<typename T>
struct Ftor
{
    explicit Ftor(const T& t) : data(t) { }
    T operator()() { std::cout << "Computed" << std::endl; return data; }
    T data;
};

int main()
{
    Scheduler<int, Ftor<int>> scheduler_ftor;
    Scheduler<int, std::function<int(void)>> scheduler_lambda;
    Ftor<int> s(5);
    scheduler_ftor.add_task(std::move(s));
    scheduler_lambda.add_task([](){ std::cout << "Computed" << std::endl; return 1; });
}
```

Why it doesn't compile?
MVS2015 is complaining about

> functional(1195): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
>   functional(1195): note: class does not define an 'operator()' or a user defined conversion operator to a pointer-to-function or reference-to-function that takes appropriate number of arguments
>   note: while compiling class template member function 'Scheduler<int,Ftor<int> >::Solver::Solver(Task &&)'

While G++ 4.9.2

> functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Scheduler<int, Ftor<int> >::Solver::*)(Ftor<int>&&)>(Ftor<int>)>’:
>   required from ‘void Scheduler<T, Task>::add_task(Task&&) [with T = int; Task = Ftor<int>]’
>
> functional:1665:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Scheduler<int, Ftor<int> >::Solver::*)(Ftor<int>&&)>(Ftor<int>)>’
>          typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;

I suppose there are some problems with std::moving to std::thread.

Comment: How is this question minimal? It looks like it the error in question could be produced from a far shorter and simpler code base. Go over every line of code and try to delete it. [Here is an example of a far more minimal example that generates the same error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/692b0058f7a6581f) without all the noise.  I just looked at each line, thought "can I delete this", and I I could, I did it (maybe changing code elsewhere to match), and recompiled to ensure the bug still happened. -1. Include "aspirational" plans, but also include minimal code: noise gets in the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use member function as first thread argument, second argument supposed to be this pointer, pointing to the object to which member function could be called to

UPDATE

Good discussion here

[Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

Comment: And the other part of the problem is? Why are you commenting, if you don't want to share your thoughts.

Comment: @Zereges before accepting, did you verify this solution solves your problem on both gcc and MSVC?  I'd bet it wouldn't work in MSVC2013, I don't know if they fixed one bug in particular in MSVC2015 that would make your code not work.

Comment: I tested it in MSVC2015 as well in GCC and it worked.

Comment: @Zereges cool, glad it worked. BTW, VC2015 RC is out just today

Comment: @Yakk MSVC2015 RC is just released today. Care to check and tell us if this bug is fixed or not? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow  your code, but **addressing the question**, a extrapolated answer will be( most of the code is **psuedocode**)
lets assume that there is a **function** `int test(int name)`.

```
thread t0;
t0 = thread(test,32); 

thread t1(test,43);
```

---

**Passing a argument to function.**

```
int temp = 0;
int testfunc(int& q)
{
  cout<<q;
}

thread t1;
t1 = thread(testfunc,ref(temp));
```

---

In short, you just pass the **name of the function** that must be run in the **thread** as the **first argument**, and the **functions parameters** follow it in same order as they are in the **function definition**, for passing by **reference** you can use the `ref()` wrapper.See the below example.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void test(int a,int &a,string test)
{
  \\do something
}

int main()
{
     int test1 = 0;
     string tt = "hello";
     thread t1;
     t1 = thread(23,&test1,tt);
     t1.detach();
     return 0;
}
```

if you are wondering about the use of `join()` and `detach()`, refer to this thread: [When should I use std::thread::detach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803600/when-should-i-use-stdthreaddetach/47049163#47049163), refer to my answer post in that thread.

Comment: +1 for pointing out my issue: I needed to wrap my pass-by-reference parameter to `std::thread()` with `std::ref()`. Ex: `std::thread t1 = std::thread(foo, std::ref(my_reference_param))` instead of `std::thread t1 = std::thread(foo, my_reference_param)`. See the `std::thread::thread()` constructor reference pg here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread: _"The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g., with `std::ref` or `std::cref`)."_

Comment: I added an answer here: [how to properly pass references to the `std::thread` constructor via `std::ref()` and `std::cref()` wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73642536/4561887)