# Execute a method in the main thread from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I put together a C++ 11 based callback timer class based on the help I got on SO on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425772/c-11-calling-a-c-function-periodically) thread.

Now what I would like to do is have this thread post a message to the main thread to call a particular function. So the `func()` call in the timer class should happen in the main thread rather than the current thread.

This is similar to the Qt `signal/slot` mechanism where the `signal` can happen in another thread but the flow gets executed in the thread of the `receiver` object. Is this possible with the C++ 11 mechanisms?

Comment: What's wrong with exactly what you described? Have a message queue that your timer thread posts messages to, and your main thread polls from?

Comment: Have a look at Boost.Asio. `io_service::post(func)` will call `func` from the thread you called `io_service::run` with, which sounds exactly like what you want in 1 line of code. It also has [timers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html)

Comment: How is the main thread polling work in this context?

Comment: Unfortunately boost is not an option in this project

Comment: Use a thread safe queue implementation like the following https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11/ to post back to the main thread. Create the queue in the main thread and pass it to the child. Then the main thread will try to `pop` from the queue, waiting on a condition variable until the child thread `push`es a message onto the queue.

Comment: You have to solve the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  This inevitably has a major impact on how the "main thread" is structured.  It is however universal in any GUI app.