# C++ Timer with reset functionality

Tags: c++, timer, callback, atomic, reset

I want a `Timer` class `with reset` method. When the `reset` method is called,  `std::function<void(void)> func` execution will be postponed for next `interval` milliseconds. Here is my code (obtained from [C++ 11: Calling a C++ function periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425772/c-11-calling-a-c-function-periodically)) (the `reset` method doesn't work correctly):

```
// .h
class Timer
{
public:
    Timer(const int interval, const std::function<void(void)>& func);
    ~Timer();
    void stop();
    void start();
    bool is_running() const noexcept;
    void reset();

private:
    const int interval_;
    const std::function<void(void)> func_;
    std::atomic<bool> execute_;
    std::thread thd_;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// .cpp

utl::Timer::Timer(const int interval, const std::function<void(void)>& func) :
    func_{ func },
    interval_{ interval },
    execute_(false)
{
}

utl::Timer::~Timer()
{
    if (execute_.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        stop();
    };
}

void utl::Timer::stop()
{
    execute_.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
    if (thd_.joinable())
        thd_.join();
}

void utl::Timer::start()
{
    if (execute_.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        stop();
    };
    execute_.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
    thd_ = std::thread([this]()
        {
            while (execute_.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
                func_();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(
                    std::chrono::milliseconds(interval_));
            }
        });
}

bool utl::Timer::is_running() const noexcept {
    return (execute_.load(std::memory_order_acquire) &&
        thd_.joinable());
}

void utl::Timer::reset()
{
    stop();
    start();
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// a main function for test
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace utl;

int main()
{
    Timer timer(5000, []() {
        cout << "reached!" << endl;
        });

    timer.start();
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "working ...";
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        timer.reset();
    }
}
```

This output of the main function (it is expected that string "reached!" not showed in cmd):

> working ...
>  reached!
>  working ...
>  reached!
>  working
> ...
>  reached!
>  .
>  .
>  .

My problems are:

1. after calling `start` the `func` object is called without any delay.
2. `reset` method does not work

Comment: The call to `func_();` is before the `sleep_for` call.  So the sleep only happens the 2nd time round.

Comment: @RichardCritten tnx. it solved my first problem.

Comment: What does "reset method does not work" mean? What is observed instead?

Comment: @JeffGarrett I updated the question with output sample.

Comment: `reset` blocks the main thread until the worker thread stops and starts again. The call to `start` always executes `func_()` at least once. It's unclear why you expect "reached!" to not be printed.