# Interrupt a detached boost::thread

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, detach

I have a class with a thread running like this :

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        void Start();
        void Stop();
        void Run();
    private:
        boost::thread mThread;
        bool mThreadShouldRun;
}

void MyClass::Start()
{
    mThreadShouldRun = true;
    mThread = boost::thread(&MyClass::Run, this);
}

void MyClass::Stop()
{
    mThreadShouldRun = false;
    mThread.interrupt();
}

void MyClass::Run()
{
    while(mThreadShouldRun)
    {
        //DO Something
        try {
            boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(15));
        } catch(boost::thread_interrupted interrupt) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is doing what i'm expecting : Launching a background thread and stopping it on demand.

But according to the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803600/when-should-i-use-stdthread-detach) `join()` or `detach()` should always be called. `join()` is not what i need in my case , so i go for `detach()` :

```
void MyClass::Start()
{
    mThreadShouldRun = true;
    mThread = boost::thread(&MyClass::Run, this);
    mThread.detach();
}
```

The thread still running as expected but `mThread` become [Not-a-Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.detach) and i can no longer interrupt it in the `Stop()` method because mThread no long reference the thread after the call to `detach()`.

**Should i really call detach() ? And if yes how to interrupt() the detached thread ?**

Comment: you have a mThreadShouldRun variable, just add a mutex an call stop form the main thread

Comment: If my thread is sleeping ,which is the case most of the time, i want to be able to stop it right away. not possible with mThreadShouldRun

Comment: ok, gonna edit the answer then

Comment: may I ask why the sleep behaviour?

Comment: It's a background thread getting information periodically (every few seconds) . Getting the information is quick but i need regular update. (something like CPU usage thread if you like)

Comment: may you use yield instead of sleep?

Comment: Yield is deprecated and sleep is what i need in this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94685/discussion-between-daniel-sanchez-and-grunk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just interrupt the thread and then wait for it to return:

```
#include <mutex>
class MyClass
{
    public:
        void Start();
        void Stop();
        void Run();
    private:
        boost::thread mThread;
        bool          mThreadShouldRun;
}

void MyClass::Start()
{
    mThreadShouldRun = true; 
    mThread = boost::thread(&MyClass::Run, this);
}

void MyClass::Stop()
{
    mThreadShouldRun = false;// dont really needed anymore but may be ok
    mThread.interrupt();
    mThread.join();
}

void MyClass::Run()
{
    while(mThreadShouldRun)
    {
        //DO Something
        try {
            boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(15));
        } catch(boost::thread_interrupted interrupt) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```