# How to add destructor for a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In C++ 11, I create a a long-live thread :

```
class Server
{
   public:
      void operator() () const {
         while(true)
            dosomething();
      }
      ~Server()
       {
         clean();
       }
};

// in main
Server s;
std::thread t(s);
t.detach();
```

I want add some clean work using a destructor when the system terminated.
However, if I add a destructor in `Server` directly, the `clean` will be called when system starts.

How to do it?

Comment: I'd say that with `std::thread t(s);` you're creating a copy of the server object. The destructor you see would in that case be the destructor of the original server object when that goes out of scope somewhere after t.detach().

Answer (score 0):

In his book (The C++ Programming Language, Chapter 42.2.5), Bjarne Stroustrup discourages from using `detach` if you don't have to and gives several reasons for that.

See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22804813/5717589.

The consequence in this case is that **the destructor** of the Server trapped in the thread **is not executed**, `cleanup()` doesn't run.

I wrote the following code to see what's happening there:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>   // for linux usleep

using namespace std;
static bool needed;   // tells the server if we need it

class Server {
public:
    Server () : id (0){
        ++id;
        cout << "Server " << id << " started. Work status: " << work_done << endl;
    }
    Server (const Server & rhs) : id (rhs.id){
        ++id;
        cout << "Server " << id << " started by copy. Work status: " << work_done << endl;
    }
    Server (Server && rhs) : id (rhs.id) {
        ++id;
        cout << "Server " << id << " started by move. Work status: " << work_done << endl;
    }

    void operator()() {
        cout << "Hi! Doing work..." << endl;
        work_done = true;
        while (needed) {
            usleep(300000);
            cout << "sleeping... Work status: " << work_done << endl;
        }
    }
    ~Server() {
        cout << "Server " << id << " stopping. Work status: " << work_done << endl;
        if (work_done)
            cout << "Cleanup triggered by Server " << id << endl;
    }
    bool work_done {false};
    int id;
};

int main() {
    needed = true;
    Server s;
//    thread t(s);
    thread t(std::move(s));
//    t.detach();
    usleep(1000000);
    needed = false;
    t.join();
    cout << "end" << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
Server 1 started. Work status: 0
Server 2 started by move. Work status: 0
Server 3 started by move. Work status: 0
Server 2 stopping. Work status: 0
Hi! Doing work...
sleeping... Work status: 1
sleeping... Work status: 1
sleeping... Work status: 1
sleeping... Work status: 1
Server 3 stopping. Work status: 1
Cleanup triggered by Server 3
end
Server 1 stopping. Work status: 0
```

With `t.detach()` on and `t.join()` off the result is:

```
Server 1 started. Work status: 0
Server 2 started by move. Work status: 0
Server 3 started by move. Work status: 0
Server 2 stopping. Work status: 0
Hi! Doing work...
sleeping... Work status: 1
sleeping... Work status: 1
sleeping... Work status: 1
end
Server 1 stopping. Work status: 0
```

(What puzzles me is some temporary instance, Server 2, which appears both with move and copy.)

Comment: needed is accessed synchronously by two threads, so this is undefined behavior.

I think the std::move(s) to the thread function isn't necessary; just pass it a reference, don't detach, and call join before Server goes out of scope.