# Is it a good practice to ran a thread from a unit test case?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, mstest

I have class which has a execute() function. Execution of execute() 
function only stops when terminate() function is called. I want to test the execute() function.

```
class Process{
public:

    void execute(){ // start execution until terminate() is called.. }

    void terminate(){ //stop the processing of execute()... }

}
```

My unit test case is given below. I am using MSTest.

```
TEST_METHOD(StartTest)
{
    Process p;
    bool isRunning = true;
    std::thread th([&](){
        p.execute();
        isRunning = false;
    });
    th.detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));

    Assert::isTrue(isRunning);
}
```

If using thread a good practice should I close the thread inside the test case instead of detaching it from main thread?

Also better suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: first of all `isRunning` is not synced. I am not sure but it looks like you are not running the thread also.

Comment: p.execute(); continues the execution of the thread.

Comment: Read this about std::thread::detach and std::terminate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803600/when-should-i-use-stdthreaddetach

Comment: @Boka I was under the impression that the constructor doesn't also run the thread. I was mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all access to `isRunning` should be synchronized. In your example you can simply use `std::atomic<bool>` and be done with it.

*Disclaimer: it's been a while since I've done any kind of serios multithreading so take this with a grain of salt. Also, I haven't tested to code, other than to check it compiles.*

This is where I would start:

```
auto test()
{
    std::condition_variable cv{};
    std::mutex m{};

    Process p{};
    bool isRunning{true};

    std::thread th([&] {
        p.execute();        
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk{m};
            isRunning = false;
        }
        cv.notify_one();
    });

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{m};
        // expect timeout
        Assert::isFalse(cv.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds(300),
                                   [&] () { return !isRunning; }));
    }

    p.terminate();

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{m};
        // expect condition to change
        Assert::isTrue(cv.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds(300),
                                   [&] () { return !isRunning; }));
    }

    th.join();
}
```

This way you check both for `execute` to block and for `terminate` to terminate and you have more flexibility. If the `execute` unblocks early you don't wait your full timeout and for `terminate` you have a wiggle to wait for the other thread to finish and you unblock as soon as it does.

---

> If terminate() fails to stop the execution, will th thread continue
>   his execution after the end of this test case?

If `terminate` doesn't stop the execution then the 2nd `wait_for` ends after timeout returning `false` and the assert kicks in. I don't know what testing framework you use and what the `Assert` does.

- if it returns the execution to `test` then the test will block on `join` until the thread finishes
- if it throws an exception then the `join` is not called and at the destructor of `th` if the thread has still not ended `std::terminate` will be called. This can be changed with a `try catch`
- if it forces an exit (e.g. calls `std::terminate`) then... well... your program ends regardless

This is indeed a problem you need to analyze. It all depends on what you want to do if `terminate` fails to stop `execute` within your wait interval.

- if you are ok with waiting within `test`, then all you need to do is make sure `join` is called. As I've said this is solvable with a `try catch`.
- if you want to end the current test but are ok with the thread still going on then you need to detach the thread if `terminate` failed to end it.
- if you want to kill the thread then... that's not possible. You could instead kill the entire app via `std::terminate`.

Comment: If terminate() fails to stop the execution, will th thread continue his execution after the end of this test case?

Comment: @Boka yeah... multithreading, especially low level multithreading is far from simple ...