# Why must one call join() or detach() before thread destruction?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I don't understand why when an `std::thread` is destructed it must be in join() or detach() state.

Join waits for the thread to finish, and detach doesn't. 
It seems that there is some middle state which I'm not understanding.
Because my understanding is that join and detach are complementary: if I don't call join() than detach() is the default.

Put it this way, let's say you're writing a program that creates a thread and only later in the life of this thread you call join(), so up until you call join the thread was basically running as if it was detached, no?

Logically detach() should be the default behavior for threads because that is the definition of what threads are, they are parallelly executed irrespective of other threads.

So when the thread object gets destructed why is terminate() called? Why can't the standard simply treat the thread as being detached?

I'm not understanding the rationale behind terminating a program when either join() or detached() wasn't called before the thread was destructed. What is the purpose of this?

**UPDATE:**

I recently came across this. Anthony Williams states in his book, Concurrency In Action, "One of the proposals for C++17 was for a joining_thread class that would be similar to std::thread, except that it would automatically join in the destructor much like scoped_thread does. This didn’t get consensus in the committee, so it wasn’t accepted into the standard (though it’s still on track for C++20 as std::jthread)..."

Comment: There was a discussion on this that I will try to find the link on, because this behaviour is different than that of `boost::thread`. Ultimately though they decided to have `std::terminate` called if it were `joinable`

Comment: See also: [When should I use `std::thread::detach` ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803600/when-should-i-use-stdthreaddetach): there are issue with letting the `main` thread exit while other threads are running.

Comment: Automatic joining in a destructor is only part of the deal. For example if you move a thread to a joinable thread it terminates as well.

Comment: Simply to help you debug code and avoid crashes. If you don't explicitly `join()` (i.e. wait for the thread to finish) and the `main` thread would finish earlier you would **crash the program** anyway. Which thread will finish first is often indeterministic and you can ignore/overlook the "unfortunate timing case" ending up with a crash on production code in most undesired moment. With *"always join() unjoinable"* rule the language reminds you that you didn't join and so you are proof from the crash for both timing profiles.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Technically the answer is "because the spec says so" but that is an obtuse answer.  We can't read the designers' minds, but here are some issues that may have contributed:

With POSIX pthreads, child threads must be joined after they have exited, or else they continue to occupy system resources (like a process table entry in the kernel).  This is done via [`pthread_join()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html).
Windows has a somewhat analogous issue if the process holds a HANDLE to the child thread; although Windows doesn't require a full join, the process must still call [`CloseHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle) to release its refcount on the thread.

Since `std::thread` is a cross-platform abstraction, it's constrained by the POSIX requirement which requires the join.

In theory the `std::thread` destructor could have called `pthread_join()` instead of throwing an exception, but that (subjectively) that may increase the risk of deadlock.  Whereas a properly written program would know when to insert the join at a safe time.

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/terminating-a-process

Comment: There's no real difference between POSIX and Windows here -- what is happening is that the process holds a reference to the thread until join or detach is called (and completes), and that means that the thread resources can't be cleaned up until the refcount drops to 0.

Answer (score 19):

You're getting confused because you're conflating the `std::thread` object with the thread of execution it refers to.  A `std::thread` object is a C++ object (a bunch of bytes in memory) that acts as a reference to a thread of execution.  When you call `std::thread::detach` what happens is that the `std::thread` object is "detached" from the thread of execution -- it no longer refers to (any) thread of execution, and the thread of execution continues running independently.  But the `std::thread` object still exists, until it is destroyed.

When a thread of execution completes, it stores its exit info into the `std::thread` object that refers to it, if there is one  (If it was detached, then there isn't one, so the exit info is just thrown away.)  It has no other effect on the `std::thread` object -- in particular the `std::thread` object is not destroyed and continues to exist until someone else destroys it.

Comment: I know `std::thread` is just a handler, and it seems you are saying that on the destruction of the handler if detach wasn't called, then the actual thread might be bound so to speak to an invalid handler/object. I understand that this is what would happen but why not by default is detach() called, it makes more sense to me that detach is called before destruction, which is essentially resorting to what would be considered default behavior. What did the standard have in mind when implementing this type of behavior which seems counter-intuitive a bit?

Comment: @MosheRabaev to force you to think about and decide how the end of the thread should be handled.

Comment: @MosheRabaev: if you want that behavior, you can stick `if (th.joinable()) th.detach();` just before `th` is destroyed (you can even wrap `std::thread` in your own thread object which does that in the destructor.)

Comment: I understand what OrangeDog said and the answer that fifoforlifo gave, it makes you think what you are doing to avoid potential problems, so I will stick to what is given :)

Comment: Am I correct in inferring that the thread of execution has a reciprocal pointer to the std::thread object that refers to it (so that it can store its exit info to the right place)?

Comment: @Wildcard: yes, that is usually how it is implemented

Answer (score 1):

You might want a thread to completely clean up after itself when it's done leaving no traces. This would mean that you could start a thread and then forget about it.

But you might also want to be able to manage a thread while it was running and get any return value it had provided when it was done. In this case, if a thread cleaned up after itself when it was done, your attempt to manage it could cause a crash because you would be accessing a handle that might be invalid. And to check for the return value when the thread finishes, the return value has to be stored somewhere, which means the thread can't be fully cleaned up because the place where the return value is stored has to be left around.

In most frameworks, by default, you get the second option. You can manage the thread (by interrupting it, sending signals to it, joining it, or whatever) but it can't clean up after itself. If you prefer the first option, there's a function to get that behavior (detach) but that means that you may not be able to access the thread because it may or may not continue to exist.

Answer (score 1):

When a thread handle for an active thread goes out of scope you have a couple of options:

1. join
2. detach
3. kill thread
4. kill program

Each one of these options is terrible. No matter which one you pick it will be surprising, confusing and not what you wanted in most situations.

---

Arguably the joining thread you mentioned already exists in the form of `std::async` which gives you a `std::future` that blocks until the created thread is done, so doing an implicit join. But the many questions about why

```cpp
std::async(std::launch::async, f);
g();
```

does not run `f` and `g` concurrently indicate how confusing that is. The best approach I'm aware of is to define it to be a programming error and have the programmer fix it, so an `assert` would be most appropriate. Unfortunately the standard went with `std::terminate` instead.

---

If you really want a detaching thread just write a little wrapper around `std::thread` that does `if (thread.joinable()) thread.detach();` in its destructor or whichever handler you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Question**: "So when the thread object gets destructed why is `terminate()` called? Why can't the standard simply treat the thread as being detached?"

**Answer**: Yes, I agree that it terminates the program badly but such design has its reasons. Without the `std::terminate()` mechanism in the destructor `std::thread::~thread`, if the users really wanted to do `join()`, but for some reason "join" didn't execute (for e.g. exception was thrown) then the new_thread will run in the background just like the `detach()` behaviors. This might cause undefined behaviors because that was not the original intention of the user to have a detached thread.