# C++ background thread in class - instance scope

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have this simple class:

```
struct Foo {        
    void Run() {
        this->bgLoader = std::thread([this]() mutable {
            //do something 

            this->onFinish_Thread();
        });
    }
    
    std::function<void()> onFinish_Thread;
    std::thread bgLoader;
};
```

That is called from C-API:

```
void CApiRunFoo(){
    Foo foo;
    foo.onFinish_Thread = []() {
        //do something at thread end
    };
    foo.Run();
}
```

I want to run `CApiRunFoo`, return from it but keep the thread running until it is finished.

Now, the problem is, that once `CApiRunFoo` end, foo goes out of scope even if background thread is still running. If I change `foo` to object via `new`, it will run, but it will cause memory leak.

I was thinking to create destructor with:

```
~Foo(){
    if (bgLoader.joinable()){
        bgLoader.join();
    }
}
```

but I am not sure if it can cause deadlock or not plus it probably wont cause `CApiRunFoo` to return until the thread finishes.

Is there any solution/design pattern to this problem?

Comment: It's difficult to comment without knowing the *desired* behaviour.  Do you want  to ensure the loading thread has finished before returning from `CApiRunFoo`?

Comment: I have edited the question - I want to run `CApiRunFoo`, return from it but keep the thread running until it is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return the `Foo` instance to the C program:

```
struct Foo {        
    ~Foo() {
        if (bgLoader.joinable()) {
            run = false;
            bgLoader.join();
        }
    }
    void Run() {
        run = true;
        this->bgLoader = std::thread([this]() mutable {
            while(run) {
                // do stuff
            }

            this->onFinish_Thread();
        });
    }
    std::atomic<bool> run;
    std::function<void()> onFinish_Thread;
    std::thread bgLoader;
};
```

The C interface:

```
extern "C" {

struct foo_t {
    void* instance;
};

foo_t CApiRunFoo() {
    Foo* ptr = new Foo;
    ptr->onFinish_Thread = []() {
        std::cout << "done\n";
    };
    ptr->Run();
    return foo_t{ptr};
}

void CApiDestroyFoo(foo_t x) {
    auto ptr = static_cast<Foo*>(x.instance);
    delete ptr;
}

}
```

And a C program:

```
int main() { 
    foo_t x = CApiRunFoo();

    CApiDestroyFoo(x);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jhWE3TfeM)

---

As it seems you'd like the `Foo` objects to automatically self destruct when the thread finishes, you could run them detached and let them `delete this;` when done.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

// Counting detached threads and making sure they are all finished before
// exiting the destructor. Used as a `static` member of `Foo`.
struct InstanceCounter {
    ~InstanceCounter() {
        run = false;
        std::unique_lock lock(mtx);
        std::cout << "waiting for " << counter << std::endl;
        while(counter) cv.wait(lock);
        std::cout << "all done" << std::endl;
    }
    void operator++() {
        std::lock_guard lock(mtx);
        std::cout << "inc: " << ++counter << std::endl;
    }
    void operator--() {
        std::lock_guard lock(mtx);
        std::cout << "dec: " << --counter << std::endl;
        cv.notify_one();      // if the destructor is waiting
    }
    std::atomic<bool> run{true};
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    unsigned counter = 0;
};

struct Foo {      
    bool Run() {        
        try {
            ++ic; // increase number of threads in static counter
            bgLoader = std::thread([this]() mutable {
                while(ic.run) {
                    // do stuff
                }
                // if onFinish_Thread may throw - you may want to try-catch:
                onFinish_Thread();
                --ic; // decrease number of threads in static counter       
                delete this; // self destruct
            });
            bgLoader.detach();
            return true;  // thread started successfully
        }
        catch(const std::system_error& ex) {
            // may actually happen if the system runs out of resources
            --ic;
            std::cout << ex.what() << ": ";
            delete this;
            return false; // thread not started
        }
    }

    std::function<void()> onFinish_Thread;

private:
    ~Foo() { // private: Only allowed to self destruct
        std::cout << "deleting myself" << std::endl;
    }

    std::thread bgLoader;
    static InstanceCounter ic;
};

InstanceCounter Foo::ic{};
```

Now the C interface becomes more like what you had in the question.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

extern "C" {

bool CApiRunFoo() {
    Foo* ptr = new Foo;
    ptr->onFinish_Thread = []() {
        std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
    };
    return ptr->Run();
    // it looks like `ptr` is leaked here, but it self destructs later
}

}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/avozxa568)

Comment: The only disadvantage is that API user must call destroy. I was thinking, if there is an "auto-destroy" solution, something like `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @MartinPerry I agree about the disadvantage - but that's how C interfaces usually work. You could however keep track of all the instances in C++ (in a `std::unordered_set<Foo>`) to automatically destroy the instances (if not done explicitly via the C interface). The C interface's `CApiDestroyFoo` would then just remove the instance from the set to destroy it - and any forgotten instances would be destroyed at program termination.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a way to transfer object ownership to thread and thread would destroy the object after calling `onFinish_Thread`. This way, I dont need to destroy object manually. With this, I cannot have join in dtor and thread shoud probably be detached.

Comment: @MartinPerry Sure, that's possible. Is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ear7Thh9M) more like what you wanted? if so I may add that as an option to the answer with some explanations.

Comment: Yes, its better, tahnk you. Add it, please, to the answer for future generations :)

Comment: @MartinPerry :-) Ok, added that (slightly modified to take care of resource exhaustion when spawning threads).

Answer (score 0):

Your program should call `join` and finish the new thread at some point in future (see also [this question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57066847/509868)). To do that, it should hold a reference (in a wide sense) to the thread object. In your current design, your `foo` is such a reference. So you are not allowed to lose it.

You should think about a place where it makes sense to do `join` in your code. This same place should hold your `foo`. If you do that, there is no problem, because `foo` contains also the `onFinish_Thread` object.