# Self terminating thread. Use join or detach

Tags: c++, multithreading, join, detach

I have a state machine being processed within a std::thread. This state machine initializes a network connection, processes data, and upon the receipt of a certain message, needs to shut itself down. Using join in this fashion triggers the 'abort() has been called' exception. Is this one of the cases where a detached thread is appropriate.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>

class ThreadExample
{
public:
    ThreadExample()
    {
        StartThread();
    }

    void StartThread()
    {
        //start thread;
        run_thread = true;
        the_thread = std::thread(&ThreadExample::ThreadFunction, this);
    }

    void ThreadFunction()
    {
        while (run_thread)
        {
            if (correct_message_found)
                ShutdownThread();
            else
                ProcessMessage();   //example code to imitate network processing

            //arbitrary wait. not relevant to the problem
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }

    //read in by some network connection
    void ProcessMessage(/*some message data*/)
    {
        static int counter = 0;
        if (counter == 3)
        {
            correct_message_found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Waiting for the right message\n";
            counter++;
        }
    }

    void ShutdownThread()
    {
        run_thread = false;
        if (the_thread.joinable())
            the_thread.join();
    }

private:
    std::thread the_thread;
    std::atomic_bool run_thread;
    bool correct_message_found = false;
};

int main()
{
    auto example = std::make_unique<ThreadExample>();

    int data;
    std::cin >> data;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the description is not clear enough. How does the thread shut itself down? Who calls `join` on what? Where would you be detaching the thread? What are the side effects of the thread and why is it threaded in the first place? Please do create the minimal representative example you are talking about, it will be much clearer. And what exactly is the question you would like answered?

Comment: I'll mock up something.

Comment: You can still exit from the thread any time you want (by returning from the threads main function), as long as someone *else* remembers to `join` the thread.

Comment: But of course you could also detach the thread, but then you should add some logic to communicate process termination to the thread (if it's still running then).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - I would imagine that the destructor is still verboten as a place to call join()?

Comment: You can't join a thread from itself. It has to be done by another thread. But it's not forbidden or prohibited to do it from a destructor, as long as it's not the thread itself that destructs the object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - that is what i had originally. I detached and ran. When the message was received to indicate that i was done with what i need, i set my poison pill variable which ended the thread loop.

Comment: you question is rather unclear. In some sense it is always the thread itself that decides when to terminate. You need to do something extra (condition variables et al) to control termination from within a different thread

Comment: Your first two sentences seem rather unconnected. "Using join in this fashion ..." in what fashion? calling `join` does not make a thread terminate, it just makes the calling thread wait until the other finishes its execution

Comment: detached thread is appropriate only if you are dealing with some old broken code that prevents thread from finishing gracefully

Comment: In conslusion to @formerlyknownas_463035818 's comment: Even if you *could* call join from within same thread, this would result in deadlock, the thread being waiting (still active!) for terminating itself... This is prevented by [join](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) (see error conditions), though.

Comment: Updated with source. Take it easy on me!

Comment: @Aconcagua Well that's exactly what's being done!

Comment: @MaxLanghof Sure, I see – code just wasn't there when I posted my comment...

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes, I didn't mean to imply you should've known, just wanted to let you know you are correct. Sorry, poor wording on my part.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Never mind ;)

Comment: @VTT, calling `detach()` is appropriate for a thread that _never_ terminates. Some people--mostly people who implement cloud service-y stuff--advocate for "crash-only code." That is, systems that have no concept of a graceful shutdown. If, for some highly unusual reason, you need the service to stop, then you just pull the plug. They argue that, since the plug could be pulled by accident anyway, then it should be sufficiently robust that pulling the plug causes no lasting harm.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Programs that are not required to perform clean shutdown are not that uncommon. For example all those new UWP apps MS is pushing. Even if code is supposed to be used inside of such a program it does not make use of `detach()` appropriate. The same code will be used in development environment or may be reused later in some other context where performing clean exit is mandatory. And the thing is that the code performing proper cleanup actions will work perfectly fine even if cleanup code is never executed at runtime, while code

Comment: with `detach()` will be completely broken when cleanup is required. Note that use of `detach` often also hides problems in underlaying code that can not be resolved by just switching to `join`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to terminate a thread from inside itself is to simply return from the function the thread is executing:

```
void ThreadFunction()
{
    while (run_thread)
    {
        if (correct_message_found)
            return;
        else
            ProcessMessage();   //example code to imitate network processing

        //arbitrary wait. not relevant to the problem
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

Calling `join` from within the thread that is supposed to be joined is an error, see the first error condition: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join

`join` means "wait for the given thread to finish, then continue on". You are telling a thread to wait until it itself is finished. So it can only end once it has already ended, which is clearly contradictory.

Where you *should* call `join` is in the destructor of `ThreadExample`. `ThreadFunction` uses members of `ThreadExample`, and `ThreadExample` also owns the `std::thread` object, so `ThreadExample` cannot be allowed to die while the thread is still running. In the code you show, you would run into that problem if you input something before the thread is done: `ThreadExample` is then destroyed, and with it the `std::thread` object living inside. If a `std::thread` is destroyed while joinable (i.e. with a non-detached thread still running) then `std::terminate` is called:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread

Comment: Thanks. I had read somewhere that it was not advised to call join in the destructor so i was avoiding that. 

for an example like this, is there a more appropriate pattern?

Comment: I'd yet add the `main` function to show where to indeed call `join`.

Comment: @Jason Where is that advice from? It is correct that you want to avoid throwing exceptions in destructors (which `std::thread::join` [might do](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join)), but you can catch that one.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803600/when-should-i-use-stdthreaddetach

Comment: @Jason I don't see how this relates to calling `join` in a destructor, except for the exact advice I provided: Destroying a `std::thread` that has neither been joined nor detached is bad.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - i was basing it on this statement:
Thus, you should always either join or detach a thread before the flows of execution reaches the destructor.

Comment: @Jason Yes, before it reaches the destructor of `std::thread`, not before it reaches _any_ destructor. Within the destructor of `ThreadExample`, `the_thread` is still alive - its destructor is called _after_ you return from `ThreadExample::~ThreadExample`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - That makes sense. Thanks for the input and patience!