# how to use = operator in threads in cpp and what is the benefit of it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

```
std::thread([=]{

//my statements and my other stuff, basically here i am updating the database accordingly some conditions.

  }).detach();
```

So, what is the use, benefit or how to use this : ***std::thread([=]***

Comment: This is about captures in the lambda.

Comment: `.detach()` is basically always the [wrong thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803600/when-should-i-use-stdthreaddetach).

Comment: Note that that is **not** the `=` operator. It's the `=` **character**, but it has a completely different role and meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code you are using lambda as std::thread function. [=] is a capture clause and means capture all external variable by value

```
auto lambdaExample = [](){ std::cout << "HELLO WORLD\n"; };
```