# Scheduling a coroutine with a context

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine

There are plenty of tutorials that explain how it's easy to use coroutines in C++, but I've spent a lot of time getting how to schedule "detached" coroutines.
Assume, I have the following definition of coroutine result type:

```
struct task {
  struct promise_type {
    auto initial_suspend() const noexcept { return std::suspend_never{}; }
    auto final_suspend() const noexcept { return std::suspend_never{}; }
    void return_void() const noexcept { }
    void unhandled_exception() const { std::terminate(); }
    task get_return_object() const noexcept { return {}; }
  };
};
```

And there is also a method that runs "detached" coroutine, i.e. runs it asynchronously.

```
/// Handler should have overloaded operator() returning task.
template<class Handler>
void schedule_coroutine(Handler &&handler) {
  std::thread([handler = std::forward<Handler>(handler)]() { handler(); }).detach();
}
```

Obviously, I can not pass lambda-functions or any other functional object that has a state into this method, because once the coroutine is suspended, the lambda passed into `std::thread` method will be destroyed with all the captured variables.

```
task coroutine_1() {
  std::vector<object> objects;
  // ...
  schedule_coroutine([objects]() -> task {
     // ...
     co_await something;
     // ...
     co_return;
  });

  // ...
  co_return;
}

int main() {
  // ...
  schedule_coroutine(coroutine_1);
  // ...
}
```

I think there is should be a way to save the `handler` somehow (preferably near or within the coroutine promise) so that the next time coroutine is resumed it won't try to access to the destroyed object data. But unfortunately I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Updated code seem to have syntax problem with misplaced `(handler)` and it is still not clear what is preventing you from saving `handler` (you can actually capture it by value with proper forwarding). Perhaps you should also check [When should I use std::thread::detach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803600/when-should-i-use-stdthreaddetach/58222149#58222149)

Comment: @DeedeeMegadoodoo: "*coroutine will be executed in another thread*" But then there's no problem with `Hander`, since the thread (it's not a coroutine at all, just a function call) will have a copy of the functor it is given. And if the "Handler" call is itself a coroutine, then you're supposed to communicate with it through its return value. That's what your lambda needs to do.

Comment: @DeedeeMegadoodoo" "*because once the coroutine is suspended, the lambda passed into std::thread method will be destroyed with all the captured variables*" That's not true. When you use a `std::thread`, all of its values are moved/copied into the new thread and will not go away until that thread terminates. Presumably, your `task` destructor will halt until the task is completed, so the lambda in your `schedule_coroutine` function will not exit until the `task` returned by `handle()` is destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is a general (and common) misunderstanding of how `co_await` coroutines are intended to work.

When a function performs `co_await <expr>`, this (generally) means that the function suspends execution until `expr` resumes its execution. That is, your function is waiting until some process completes (and typically returns a value). That process, represented by `expr`, is the one who is supposed to resume the function (generally).

The whole point of this is to make code that executes asynchronously *look like* synchronous code as much as possible. In synchronous code, you would do something like `<expr>.wait()`, where `wait` is a function that waits for the task represented by `expr` to complete. Instead of "waiting" on it, you "a-wait" or "asynchronously wait" on it. The rest of your function executes asynchronously relative to your caller, based on when `expr` completes and how it decides to resume your function's execution. In this way, `co_await <expr>` looks and appears to act very much like `<expr>.wait()`.

Compiler Magic<sup>tm</sup> then goes in behind the scenes to make it asynchronous.

So the idea of launching a "detached coroutine" doesn't make sense within this framework. The caller of a coroutine function (usually) isn't the one who determines where the coroutine executes; it's the processes the coroutine invokes during its execution that decides that.

Your `schedule_coroutine` function really ought to just be a regular "execute a function asynchronously" operation. It shouldn't have any particular association with coroutines, nor any expectation that the given functor is or represents some asynchronous task or if it happens to invoke `co_await`. The function is just going to create a new thread and execute a function on it.

Just as you would have done pre-C++20.

If your `task` type represents an asynchronous task, then in proper RAII style, its destructor ought to wait until the task is completed before exiting (this includes any resumptions of coroutines scheduled by that task, throughout the entire execution of said task. The task isn't done until it is *entirely* done). Therefore, if `handler()` in your `schedule_coroutine` call returns a `task`, then that `task` will be initialized and immediately destroyed. Since the destructor waits for the asynchronous task to complete, the thread will not die until the task is done. And since the thread's functor is copied/moved from the function object given to the `thread` constructor, any captures will continue to exist until the thread itself exits.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got you right, but I think there might be a couple of misconceptions here. First off, you clearly cannot detach a coroutine, that would not make any sense at all. But you can execute asynchronous tasks inside a coroutine for sure, even though in my opinion this defeats its purpose entirely.

But let's take a look at the second block of code you posted. Here you invoke `std::async` and forward a handler to it. Now, in order to prevent any kind of early destruction you should use `std::move` instead and pass the handler to the lambda so it will be kept alive for as long as the scope of the lambda function is valid. This should probably already answer your final question as well, because the place where you want this handler to be stored would be the lambda capture itself.

Another thing that bothers me is the usage of `std::async`. The call will return a `std::future`-kind of type that will block until the lambda has been executed. But this will only happen if you set the launch type to `std::launch::async`, otherwise you will need to call `.get()` or `.wait()` on the future as the default launch type is `std::launch::deferred` and this will only lazy fire (meaning: when you actually request the result).

So, in your case and if you really wanted to use coroutines that way, I would suggest to use a `std::thread` instead and store it for a later `join()` somewhere pseudo-globally. But again, I don't think you would really want to use coroutines mechanics that way.

Comment: I forgot that std::async returns the future thread that should be awaited in any case, this isn't what I was meaning. The only thing I want is to run a coroutine in a separate thread, just spawn and forget about it... at least for now.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't got your example right. As far as I can see there is no coroutine at all, so it is really hard to understand what you want to achieve here.

So, when you want to spawn a coroutine asynchronously, meaning in a task somewhere else, then I don't see why this would not work. The problem you're facing with ownership on the other hand is a clear indication that your intended design might just be a little bit off or, in other words, when you want to detach something you should either already know a global place to store the results or do not detach it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes perfect sense, the misunderstanding is `C++20 coroutines` are actually generators mistakenly occupying `coroutine` header name.

Let me explain how generators work and then answer how to schedule detached coroutine.

## How generators work

Your question `Scheduling a detached coroutine` then looks `How to schedule a detached generator` and answer is: `not possible` because **special convention** transforms regular function into generator function.

What is not obvious right there is the **yielding** a value **must** take place inside generator function body. When you want to **call a helper function** that yields value for you - you can't. Instead you also make **a helper function** into generator and then `await` instead of just calling helper function. This effectively chains generators and might feel like writing synchronous code that executes async.

In Javascript **special convention** is `async` keyword. In Python **special convention** is `yield` instead of return keyword.

The `C++20 coroutines` are low level mechanism allowing to implement Javascipt like async/await.

Nothing wrong with including this low-level mechanism in C++ language except placing it in header named `coroutine`.

## How to schedule detached coroutine

This question makes sense if you want to have `green threads` or `fibers` and you are writing scheduler logic that uses symmetric or asymmetric coroutines to accomplish this.

Now others might ask: why should anyone bother with fibers(not windows fibers;) when you have generators? **The** answer is because you can have **encapsulated** concurrency and parallelism logic, meaning rest of your team isn't required to learn and apply additional mental gymnastics while working on the project.

The result is **true asynchronous programming** where the rest of the team write linear code, without callbacks and such, with simple concept of concurrency for example single `spawn()` library function, avoiding any locks/mutexes and other multithreading complexity.

The beauty of encapsulation is seen when all details are hidden in low level i/o methods. All context switching, scheduling, etc. happens deep inside i/o classes like `Channel`, `Queue` or `File`.

Everyone involved in **async programming** should experience working like this. The feeling is intense.

To accomplish this instead of `C++20 coroutines` use [Boost::fiber](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/index.html) that includes scheduler or [Boost::context](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/context/doc/html/index.html) that allows symmetric coroutines. Symmetric coroutines allow to suspend and switch to any other coroutine while asymmetric coroutines suspend and resume calling coroutine.