# self destructive std:thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I'm going to have a function capable of generating auto-destructive threads. The problem is that I'm not allowed to reuse the function until the created thread has finished. On the other hand, I want the spawned thread to continue running outside the scope of the function and be destroyed whenever the thread is done.

My code is as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

struct ThreadGaurd
{
public:

    ThreadGaurd(void (*Func) (int) , int number);

    ~ThreadGaurd();
private:
public:

    std::thread m_Thread;
private:
};


void CreateThread()
{
    static int Counter = 0;
    ThreadGaurd m_Thread([](int counter)
    {
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> m_Duration(500);

        while (true) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(m_Duration);

            std::cout << "My " << counter << "'th Thread is Running";
        }
    }, Counter);

    return;
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CreateThread();
    CreateThread();
    return 0;
}

ThreadGaurd::ThreadGaurd(void (*Func)(int), int number) : m_Thread(Func,number)
{
}

ThreadGaurd::~ThreadGaurd()
{
    if (m_Thread.joinable())
        m_Thread.join(); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to call [`std::thread::detach`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) on the thread. After `detach` returns, it is safe to destroy the `std::thread` object as the thread is no longer associated with the object and will continue running independently.

The following code demonstrates using `detach`.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using std::cout, std::endl;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

template<class F>
void create_detached_thread(F&& func) {
    std::thread th{std::forward<F>(func)};
    th.detach();
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    cout << "Main started" << endl;

    create_detached_thread([]() {
        cout << "First thread starting" << endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(400ms);
        cout << "First thread done" << endl;

    });

    create_detached_thread([]() {
        cout << "Second thread starting" << endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);
        cout << "Second thread done" << endl;
    });

    cout << "Main sleeping" << endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    cout << "Main done" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Main started
Main sleeping
Second thread starting
First thread starting
Second thread done
First thread done
Main done
```

As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22804813/1202808), you have to call either `join` or `detach` on a thread before the `std::thread` object is destroyed, otherwise `std::terminate` is called.

If you need to use `detach`, you will probably want to provide a synchronization mechanism so that the main thread will not end unless all of the `detach`'ed threads have finished.

**Update**

The following code is the same as above except it uses a `std::atomic<int>` to wait for the two detached threads to finish before allowing `main` to finish.

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using std::cout, std::endl;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

template<class F>
void create_detached_thread(F&& func) {
    std::thread th{std::forward<F>(func)};
    th.detach();
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    cout << "Main started" << endl;

    std::atomic<int> ndone{};

    create_detached_thread([&]() {
        cout << "First thread starting" << endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(400ms);
        cout << "First thread done" << endl;
        ++ndone;
        ndone.notify_one();
    });

    create_detached_thread([&]() {
        cout << "Second thread starting" << endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);
        cout << "Second thread done" << endl;
        ++ndone;
        ndone.notify_one();
    });

    cout << "Main sleeping" << endl;
    ndone.wait(0);
    ndone.wait(1);
    cout << "Main done" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of waiting to finish, use `std::jthread` with`std::stop_token` for automatic `join` on destruction.