# how to not block parent with waitpid

Tags: c, unix, parallel-processing, posix, child-process

I need to create a program that creates n number of processes and displays information.  When each process ends, I am to print it's PID and the exit status.  The way I am doing it, the parent program waits to create the next process until the current one ends.  I need it so that it keeps creating the child processes and just displays the exit information when ever one process ends without blocking the parent from continuing.  I can;t figure out where to put my wait to ensure this.  Below is my code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
     printf("\n\nUsage: %s <enter a number (12 or less)>\n\n", argv[0]);
     exit (-1);
  }
  else
  {
    int *processNum = (int *)malloc(sizeof(12));
    int processNumTemp;

    processNumTemp = atoi(argv[1]);
    processNum = &processNumTemp;

  if(*processNum > 12 || *processNum < 1)
    {
      printf("\n\nUsage: %s <enter a number (12 or lrss)>\n\n", argv[0]);
    }
  else
    {
      parentInfo(processNum);
      createChildProcess(processNum);
    }


  }

 return 0;
}


//Name:  parentInfo
//Description:  Displays information about the parent process
//Parameters:  processNum - stores the number of child processes to create
//             (entered at the command line).
//Return:  none
void parentInfo(int *processNum)
{
 printf("Parent process ID:  %d\n", getppid());
 printf("Number of processes to create:  %d\n", *processNum);
}


//Name:  createChildProcess
//Description:  Creates n number of child processes.
//              For each child process, it says its a child process and it
//              displays its PID.
//              After each child process closes, the parent displays info.
//Parameters:  processNum - stores the number of child processes to create
//             (entered at the command line).
//Return:  none
void createChildProcess(int *processNum)
{
 int i;
 int childStatus;
 pid_t childpid;

 /*The for loop will create n number of processes based on the value of            processNum.*/
 for(i = 1; i <= *processNum; i++)
 childpid = fork();

  //Executes if fork didn't work
  if(childpid < 0)
    {
      perror("fork");
      exit(1);
    }

  //Executes if the fork worked
  else if( childpid == 0)
    {
      int pid = getpid();

      //Prints a message and the child processe's PID
      printf("\nHello I am a child process.\n");
      printf("My PID is %d. \n", getpid());

      for(int x = 1; x <= pid; x ++);

      exit(15);
    }

}
      //Executes after the child process has ended
      //Checks the child process's exit status

      waitpid(childpid, &childStatus, WUNTRACED);
      printf("\nPID of the child process that was just created:  %d.\n", childpid);

      if(WIFEXITED(childStatus))
        {
          printf("PID %d exited normally.  Exit number:  %d\n", childpid, WEXITSTATUS(childStatus));
        }
      else if(WIFSTOPPED(childStatus))
        {
          printf("PID %d was stopped by %d\n", childpid, WSTOPSIG(childStatus));
        }
      else if(WIFSIGNALED(childStatus))
        {
          printf("PID %d exited due to signal %d\n.", childpid, WTERMSIG(childStatus));
        }
      else
        {
          perror("waitpid");
        }
}
```

Comment: Set up a signal handler for SIGCHLD.  Call `wait` in the handler.

Answer (score 4):

Before `fork` code

```
signal(SIGCHLD, childHandler);
```

In childHandler put your `waitpid` code.

```
void childHandler(int signum)
{

    pid_t childpid;
    int childstatus;

    while ((childpid = waitpid( -1, &childstatus, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    {
        if (WIFEXITED(childStatus))
        {
            printf("PID %d exited normally.  Exit number:  %d\n", childpid, WEXITSTATUS(childStatus));
        }
        else
            if (WIFSTOPPED(childStatus))
            {
                printf("PID %d was stopped by %d\n", childpid, WSTOPSIG(childStatus));
            }
            else
                if (WIFSIGNALED(childStatus))
                {
                    printf("PID %d exited due to signal %d\n.", childpid, WTERMSIG(childStatus));
                }
                else
                {
                    perror("waitpid");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

You should not use async-unsafe calls like `printf` inside a signal handler so alter your code to save the status in a global or heap allocated array - you know the size to create from processNum - and print the status info outside the handler.

Also, as currently structured, your parent could end before reaping all the children.  Add a counter for the children so that you wait on all of them before the parent exits.

Answer (score 0):

Look into signal `SIGCHLD`. If you have it blocked, you must unblock it or might instead explicitly check for it.

Comment: What's a detached child?

Comment: See Stackoverflow post [Detached vs. Joinable POSIX threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756882/detached-vs-joinable-posix-threads). THe only important thing in this case is they are not detached.

Comment: OP is creating processes not threads.  This is irrelevant.  Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `wait` is to, well, wait, so the way to solve your problem is to first create all the children, then start waiting for them to terminate.
Here is a program which does that:

```
// fork
#include <unistd.h>

// wait
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// exit
#include <stdlib.h>

//printf
#include <stdio.h>

void child( int id)
{
  int seed= id;
  int x= rand_r( &seed) % 10;
  sleep( x);

  exit( x);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const int n= 5;
  int i;

  printf( "creating %d children.\n", n);
  for ( i= 0; i < n; ++i) {
    pid_t pid= fork();
    if ( !pid)
      child( i); // does not return
    else
      printf( "child [0x%x] created.\n", pid);
  }

  // all the children are created now
  // now we wait for them to terminate

  printf( "waiting for children to terminate.\n", n);
  for ( i= 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int result;
    pid_t pid= wait( &result);
    printf( "child [0x%x] terminated with result [%u].\n", pid, WEXITSTATUS( result));
  }

  puts( "all children terminated.");
}
```