# Why this piece of code run without any output (about pthread)?

Tags: c, pthreads

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdio>

void *printa(void *) {
    printf("a");
    return NULL;
}

void *printb(void *) {
    printf("b");
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t pa, pb;
    pthread_create(&pa, NULL, printa, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pb, NULL, printb, NULL);
    for(;;);
}
```

I expect it to print "a" and "b" in any order, but it can run and exit without print anything. Why?
ADD:
So the reason is the main function exit before the threads was run.
So I add a for(;;); in the end of main, and it seems that "a" and "b" is never printed.

Answer (score 2):

Your program exits before threads are done processing, you need to wait for each thread to finish with `pthread_join`

Comment: ...or some other mechanism that prevents early process termination.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` (actually *stdout*) is generally line buffered. See [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) and [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html). So the `"a"` and `"b"` strings stay in  the internal buffer of `stdout` and you don't observe any output ...

Either add a `\n` in your `printf`, or call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) (perhaps as `fflush(NULL);` ....) in both `printa` and `printb`. See also [flockfile(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/flockfile.3.html).

And you should call [pthread_join(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) on both `pa` and `pb` in your `main` after the calls to `pthread_create`, or else have detached threads e.g. with [pthread_detach(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3756882/841108).

Read some good [**Pthread tutorial**](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). See also [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html).

BTW, the busy loop `for(;;);` is bad taste (and not environment-friendly: you are wasting power uselessly). Prefer some idle loop, perhaps using [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html), [nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html), [pause(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html), etc; or some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (around  [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), etc...).Of course a call to `pthread_join` will wait for the thread to terminate.